# How to connect to a remote computer running a sql database via php

Tags: php, mysql

I am running an apache webserver on a server on my local network.

I have a microsoft SQL server 2008 r2 database running on a different machine on the same network. My webserver is hosting a lot of pages, and are all fine and can be accessed locally and externally. However, when I try to connect to the SQL database using php, I get hit with the following error.:

**Failed to connect to MySQL: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

I am at a total loss at this point as I have opened port 1433 and have spent hours trying to figure this out.

The code that I am using is a very basic connect script:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("mycomputer", "myname", "password", "my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

If anyone can help, I would sincerely appreciate it as iIam about to give up on this project!!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mysqli` is specifically dedicated to connecting to MySQL. If you want to connect to other DBMSs then you must use PDO. => http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

As i understand - you use MS SQL , so you must use mssql_connect  not as mysqli_connect

Check [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php)

Cause its another database and another driver (extension ) using to connect